# Kafka: Retrieving the topic lag in parallel with poll()

Tags: java, apache-kafka, thread-safety, metrics, lag

`What is the best way to retrieve the Kafka topic lag in parallel with poll (from the same process)?

1. Using the same consumer and calculate the lag using consumer.committed and consumer.endOffsets in parallel with poll() will results with unsafe thread error.
2. Using another instance of the same consumer should solve the thread safe issue but will results with rebalancing partitions between both consumer instances. (and one is only for retrieving this metric, not for polling)
3. Using AdminClient, I cant find a way to retrieve the end offsets..

So what should be the way to achieve this ?

Something like this :

```
partitions = metricConsumer.partitionsFor(kafkaConfiguration.getTopicName()).stream().map(p -> new TopicPartition(kafkaConfiguration.getTopicName(), p.partition()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            endOffsets = metricConsumer.endOffsets(partitions);
            Set<TopicPartition> endsOffsetPartitions = endOffsets.keySet();
            commitOffsets = metricConsumer.committed(endsOffsetPartitions);

            commitOffsets.forEach((topicPartition, offsetAndMetadata) -> lag.addAndGet(endOffsets.get(topicPartition) - offsetAndMetadata.offset())) ;
```

Comment: Why do you need to get the lag in parallel with the poll, this should not be a normal flow, by all means its better to split such tasks. and in another process or maybe application listen to the topics partition lag and report actions to any other system wants to take action on it, but the consumer instance itself doesn't have to bother itself with such headache.

Comment: I don't think KafkaAdminClient have out of the box lag reporter, however you can write it simply, here is an example https://www.baeldung.com/java-kafka-consumer-lag

Comment: This is a requierment.. we have one process that do the poling and we should also report about the lag metric. we can not do this in sync because calculating the lag take long tome (2 seconds)

I already see the sample in that link :  https://www.baeldung.com/java-kafka-consumer-lag   but it is using consumer.endOffsets to get the end offsets which is not thread safe .. (its not using the adminClient to get the end offset)

Comment: That’s exactly why is not recommended, that the normal processing will be greatly impacted by the consumer lag time, which is a not scalable option, specially if you have a topic with multiple partitions or the traffic is little bit high, you will end up with a lag anyways due to the fact you are measuring the lag

Comment: Don't measure from Java if you want to consume faster (reduce lag). Use external tools like Burrow that monitor your offsets topic externally. Otherwise, lag is already a JMX metric, so you should never be calling blocking Java methods within your client to fetch offsets

Comment: OK thank you !, but an option is to use listOffsets (from AdminClient) to get the end offsets.